# call.enqueue dose not work and response.body is null in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

When calling json link only give Header value `Authorization=token`, response is null. `onResponse` method is not working, but there is no error. No reach On failure stage. How I get any JSON data?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Comment: Here is my code link
-------------
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EDRuPxAH0E8XW7zz7ApEFa68IlxQaRB3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You didn't post your code, and your question is not really clear.

Comment: I can call JSON from postman.
Here is my Screen Shot
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rgEu1gVfOnuZ-kpAraYqOV9OI4cKoR6A

Comment: I posted code from link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EDRuPxAH0E8XW7zz7ApEFa68IlxQaRB3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

you will get response code from the response 
try this way to handle request response 
and handle your error messages according to the response code

```
 public void onResponse(Call<DDL> call, Response<DDL> response) {

                            if (response.code()==200) {
Log.e("Here Arrived ID", response.body().getId());
                                try {

                                    DDLList = (List<DDL>) response.body();
                                    a = response.body().getProcessCode();
                                    Log.e("Here Arrived 2", "arlala");

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(convertView.getContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("Here Arrived 3", "nodata");
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.e("Here Arrived 4", "json is null");
                                //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

Comment: I can catch my error .For now it is okay.Thanks Milan Pansuriya